# NullReferenceException on join with Postgres EF Provider

Tags: postgresql, linq, asp.net-core

I have a postgres database and using asp.net core mvc (+ ef). The database is created correctly. I have two tables 'Module' and 'ModuleMenu'. I want to get all the menu's for a given module but I keep on failing to create the linq query.

Situation

**Model: Module.cs**

```
namespace project.Model
{
    public class Module
    {    
        [Required]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Model: ModuleMenu.cs**

```
namespace project.Models
{
    public class ModuleMenu
    {
        [Required]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public int ModuleID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ModuleID")]
        public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
namespace project.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


        public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ModuleMenu> ModuleMenus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
public List<ModuleMenu> GetModuleMenus(){
    var query = from m in _dbContext.ModuleMenus
                join mod in _dbContext.Modules on 
                    m.ModuleID equals mod.ID
                select m;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

**Error**

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can anyone help me to correctly create the query?

Comment: Wouter, please read this help center http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging topic on how to properly use tags and why not to force them into the question title. Rather use the title to describe your problem in a short sentence, then people will have it easier to guess from the question page if they may have an answer to you or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this part correct in your code?

```
public int ModuleID { get; set; }
```

It seems that you might have had an error in the type used for the fk.
Below I changed the type to be string rather than int.

```
public string ModuleID { get; set; }
```

based on that update, the query could look like this.

```
public ModuleMenu[] GetModuleMenusForModule(string moduleId)
{
    return _dbContext.ModuleMenus.Where(x => x.ModuleID == moduleId).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that model to error (ModelID and ID are incompatible types). If that were correct, your code should work. Or simpler:

```
public List<ModuleMenu> GetModuleMenus()
{
    return _dbContext.ModuleMenus.ToList();
}
```